linear fit within rolling_map slow for python-polars
I have a timeseries dataset as a polars(v0.20.6) pl.DataFrame which features strong seasonality, which is well predicted and modelled by one hour ahead (linear) forecasts.
At the moment, this is incredibly slow, causes memory issues and eventually a python kernel crash.
As an example, I am using a ~2m row pl.DataFrame with ~300cols which is a timeseries dataset at minutely frequency. On this data I am running
def ols_slope(y: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # Calculate linear regression slope
    x = y.rank("ordinal")
    numerator = ((x - x.mean())*(y - y.mean())).sum()
    denominator = ((x - x.mean())**2).sum()
    return numerator / denominator

def ols_offset(y: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # Calculate linear regression offset
    x = y.rank("ordinal")
    numerator = ((x - x.mean())*(y - y.mean())).sum()
    denominator = ((x - x.mean())**2).sum()
    return (numerator / denominator) * x.mean() - y.mean()

on a date_utc+value col to get a local linear fit by using
raw_data = ( 
  pl.read_ipc("../data_vault_1min.feather")
  .with_columns(
      [
        pl.col("A1").rolling_map(ols_slope, window_size=60, min_periods=3).alias("A1_hourly_lin_pred"),
        pl.col("A1").rolling_map(ols_slope, window_size=60, min_periods=3).alias("A1_hourly_lin_pred")
      ]
  )
)

Under the hood, as far as I can see this is performing a group_by_dynamic(), which I would expect to be fairly performant.
Yet this single operation always maxes out my complete memory & leads to a kernel crash.
It runs well on a small subset of data <1k rows, but already for ~50k rows this takes over 5min to run for me, and uses all of my 32GB of memory I have.

I believe rolling_map has its own implementation (it materializes actual Series objects and passes them to the function) - hence the performance warnings in the docs. As your logic is all Polars expressions, can't this be done using .rolling()?

Next to my answer below, taking a look at the polars_ds extension might also be worthwhile.

Will take a look - at a first glance not relevant to this project, but sure to come in handy for the future!

updated the above to be much more efficient:
    # Calculate linear regression a * x + b
    n = y.count()
    x_sum = x.sum()
    y_sum = y.sum()
    x_s_sq = (x**2).sum()
    xy_sum = (x * y).sum()
    slope = (n * xy_sum - x_sum * y_sum) / (n * x_s_sq - x_sum**2 + pl.lit(1e-5))
    offset = (y_sum - slope * x_sum) / n
    return slope * (n + pred_dist) + offset```

As @jqurious mentioned in the comments, you could try using pl.DataFrame.rolling instead.
Example data
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

N = 100_000

start_date = datetime(2024, 1, 1)
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=N)

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "date": np.arange(start_date, end_date, timedelta(days=1)),
    "price": np.linspace(1, 10, N) ** 3,
})

Implementation using pl.DataFrame.rolling
For the aggregation of the remaining columns in the dataframe, we use pl.Expr.last. This will keep the columns unaffected by the aggregation.
Moreover, as of April 2024 pl.DataFrame.rolling doesn't support a min_periods parameters as pl.Expr.rolling_map does. Still, we can obtain this behaviour using a pl.when().then() construct.
(
    df
    .rolling(index_column="date", period="60d", check_sorted=False)
    .agg(
        pl.exclude("date").last(),
        pl.when(pl.len() >= 3).then(ols_slope(pl.col("price")).alias("price_slope")),
        pl.when(pl.len() >= 3).then(ols_offset(pl.col("price")).alias("price_offset")),
    )
)

shape: (100_000, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date                ┆ price      ┆ price_slope ┆ price_offset │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ f64          │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0        ┆ null        ┆ null         │
│ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1.00027    ┆ null        ┆ null         │
│ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 1.00054    ┆ 0.00027     ┆ -0.99973     │
│ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 1.00081    ┆ 0.00027     ┆ -0.99973     │
│ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 1.00108    ┆ 0.00027     ┆ -0.99973     │
│ …                   ┆ …          ┆ …           ┆ …            │
│ 2297-10-11 00:00:00 ┆ 999.892003 ┆ 0.026984    ┆ -998.272825  │
│ 2297-10-12 00:00:00 ┆ 999.919001 ┆ 0.026984    ┆ -998.299794  │
│ 2297-10-13 00:00:00 ┆ 999.946    ┆ 0.026985    ┆ -998.326764  │
│ 2297-10-14 00:00:00 ┆ 999.973    ┆ 0.026985    ┆ -998.353734  │
│ 2297-10-15 00:00:00 ┆ 1000.0     ┆ 0.026986    ┆ -998.380705  │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘

For N = 100_000, this takes ~340ms on my machine - in contrast to ~12.2s for the implementation using pl.Expr.rolling_map.

Thanks Hericks, worked a charm! The only thing I needed to change was adding a .sort("date"), as my polars 0.20.6 did not accept the .rolling(..., check_sorted=False) flag ¯_(ツ)_/¯
